# Help with the Texas Instruments TXS0101 for level shifting

Tags: arduino, digital-logic, component-selection

I am considering the [TXS0101](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txs0101.pdf) for my project, which essentially is multiple I2C sensors paired with an ESP32.

As the I2C for an ESP32 is 3.3V logic and some of my sensors are 5V, a TXS0101 seems to solve my needs quite nicely and even takes care of the I2C line pull up resistors.

The datasheets for these chips all suggest that the MCU is the LV side, not the HV side. While this is true in this particular case and not an issue, naturally I am thinking about "what's next."

The OE pin of the TXS0101 appears to require LV connection, so would I be correct in saying that the solution would be to just voltage divide down my OE output pin of a 5v MCU and tie that around to the OE input on the TXS0101 but still wire in the HV MCU into the HV pins?

Comment: Based on other questions here, using the TXS0101 for I2C will likely fail with spectacular consequences, unless the TXS0101 is used under precise conditions set in the data sheet. What are your usage conditions? How much is the distance or wiring between devices?

Answer (score 1):

The OE input has a wide operating range.

For \$V_{CCA} = 3.3V\$ and \$V_{CCB} = 5V\$:

- \$V_{IH,min} = V_{CCA}*0.65 = 2.145V\$
- \$V_{IH,max} = 5.5V\$
- \$V_{IL,min} = 0V\$
- \$V_{IH,max} = V_{CCA}*0.35 = 1.155V\$

So in your case you can drive the input from either voltage domain.

From the datasheet, page 5:
[image]